# How can I use same url in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to user same url but in different view, how can I do this?

here my urls

```
  url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)/$', QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
  url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)/$', QuestionUniListView.as_view(), name='uni-list'),
```

this slugs get different models. When I run like this only one url works?

Answer (score 0):

Django url keeps searching for the pattern from the top of the file. When it matches the pattern it render the requeat and stop further execution. So, its not possible to have same urls.

You should try changing some keyword in the url

Comment: I understand you thanks your answer but how can ı use two different slug in one url from diffrent models can you give an example "www.site.com/uni/<slug>/ask/<slug>/" ı want to use like this?

Comment: It is not passed as such. If you want to search for two things. Pass the slug like <slug1-slug2>. Then seperate these two using python programing using .split(), after that you can use these two as you will get 2 slugs from one. Now, use them to filter 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try with different slug name for both urls as below

```
 url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)/$', QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
 url(r'^(?P<list_slug>\S+)/$', QuestionUniListView.as_view(), name='uni-list'),
```

and in your Html where you are calling this url pass as below

```
{% url 'uni-list' list_slug='{{ your_slug }}' %}
```